# How to add cooldowns on discord.py hybrid commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.all()
        intents.message_content = True
        super().__init__(command_prefix = "!", case_insensitive = True,intents = intents, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='/info'))
      

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.tree.sync()
        await self.tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = guild_id))
        print(f"Synced slash commands for {self.user}")
     
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send("You're in cooldown. Try again later")

bot = Bot()

@bot.hybrid_command(name = "command", with_app_command = True, description = "This is a test command")
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def command(ctx: commands.Context):
```

I tried this but the bot doesn't respond when the command is triggered on cooldown, and I get the error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'CommandOnCooldown'`. What am I missing?

Comment: where did you define dict? inside your command function?

Comment: @TimG233, well to be honest I don't know exactly how to do that, and not even if I should or shouldn't do that. I'm just a starter in discord and python, and most of my bot is made through tutorials. But I think it's important to mention that there's a event listener on my bot, that works for a "group of commands" for example, everytime the message starts with "!", It will check if it matches one of these commands, if yes it'll execute the command, if not it'll send the closest match, in this event, there's a dictionary with these commands

Comment: Although I don't want them to have any kind of cooldown, but I just discovered that removing it from the code, makes the code I sent above working perfectly, any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: As shown in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=hybrid#discord.ext.commands.HybridCommand), I believe you can create a command hybrid group, and then add a cooldown.